# how to set path of bucket in amazonsagemaker jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to the aws how to set path of my bucket and access file of that bucket?

Is there anything i need to change with prefix ?

```
import os
import boto3
import re
import copy
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()

region = boto3.Session().region_name

bucket='ltfs1' # Replace with your s3 bucket name
prefix = 'sagemaker/ltfs1' # Used as part of the path in the bucket where you store data
# bucket_path = 'https://s3-{}.amazonaws.com/{}'.format(region,bucket) # The URL to access the bucket
```

I'm using the above code but it's showing file not found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file you are accessing is in the root directory of your s3 bucket, you can access the file like this:

```
import pandas as pd

bucket='ltfs1'
data_key = 'data.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
training_data = pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "sage.session.s3_input" to specify the location of s3 bucket where the training data is present.

Below is sample code:

```
import sagemaker as sage
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()
sess = sage.Session()

bucket= 'dev.xxxx.sagemaker'
prefix="EstimatorName"

s3_training_file_location = "s3://{}/csv".format(bucket) 
data_location_config = sage.session.s3_input(s3_data=s3_training_file_location, content_type="csv")

output_path="s3://{}/{}".format(bucket,prefix)


account = sess.boto_session.client('sts').get_caller_identity()['Account']
region = sess.boto_session.region_name
image = '{}.dkr.ecr.{}.amazonaws.com/CustomEstimator:latest'.format(account, region)
print(image) 
# xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-heast-1.amazonaws.com/CustomEstimator:latest

tree = sage.estimator.Estimator(image,
                       role, 1, 'ml.c4.2xlarge',
                       base_job_name='CustomJobName',
                       code_location=output_path,
                       output_path=output_path,
                       sagemaker_session=sess)

tree.fit(data_location_config)
```